# Firebase Nested Query

Tags: nested, firebase, subquery, firebasesimplelogin, rest-firebase

I am new to firebase and have read through the docs, but can't seem to find a away to get a list of all Ladders with populated User data. I don't really want to duplicate the user data in every ladder they are a member of.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
"ladders" : [ {
    "description" : "Real Real Tennis",
    "name" : "Ping Pong",
    "players" : {
      "simplelogin:5" : true
    }
  }, {
    "description" : "Real Tennis",
    "name" : "Mario Tennis",
    "players" : {
      "simplelogin:5" : true
    }
  } ],
  "users" : {
    "simplelogin:5" : {
      "email" : "bob@bob.com",
      "md5hash" : "1e737a7b6e1f0afb1d6fef521097400b",
      "name" : "Bob",
      "username" : "bob1"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my best attempt, but it looks like the ladders lookup finishes and returns before the users lookup is done so it returns with players being empty.

```
laddersRef.on('value', function(laddersSnapShot){
        var ladders = []
        laddersSnapShot.forEach(function(ladderData) {
            var ladder = ladderData.val();
            ladder.players = [];
            ladder.id = ladderData.key();

            laddersRef.child(ladder.id).child('players').on('value', function(snap){
                snap.forEach(function(player){
                    usersRef.child(player.key()).on('value', function(snap1){
                        ladder.players.push(snap1.val())
                    })
                })
            })
            ladders.push(ladder)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most everything about this example is broken. A read through [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) is essential before this question can be answered in a meaningful way. As written, your code establishes a new listener on each ladder's list of players any time any field anywhere in ladders/ is modified.

This occurs because laddersRef.on('value') will be updated any time there is a change anywhere in that path. Each time this occurs, you then establish laddersRef.child(ladder.id).child('players').on('value'), which creates multiple listeners on each ladder's players/ path. The fundamentals of this are covered in [retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html)

The correct answer here is to utilize the tools as intended, rather than trying to make a slow, tedious, error-prone and synchronous process out of asynchronous API methods.

To directly answer your question, this is what you asked for:

```
function done(ladders) {
   console.log(ladders);
}

laddersRef.on('value', function(laddersSnapShot){
  function doneWithLadder() {
     if( ++laddersDone === laddersNeeded ) {
       done(ladders);
     }
  }

  var ladders = [];
  var laddersDone = 0;
  var laddersNeeded = laddersSnapShot.numChildren();

  laddersSnapShot.forEach(function(ladderData) {
    var ladder = ladderData.val();
    var playersFound = 0;
    var playersNeeded = ladderData.numChildren();
    ladder.players = [];
    ladder.id = ladderData.key();
    laddersSnapshot.child('players').forEach(function(ps) {
       usersRef.child(ps.key()).once('value', function(userSnap) {
           ladder.players.push(usersSnap.val());
           if( ++playersFound === playersNeeded ) {
              doneWithLadder();
           }
       });
    });
  });
});
```

But this is more elegant (and much more elegant would be to use a framework and avoid this entirely):

```
function addLadder(snap) {
   putLadderInDom(snap.key(), snap.val());
   snap.ref().child('players').on('value', changePlayers);
   // Use whatever framework you have available to put this into
   // the DOM. Be sure to keep the record key around so you can
   // add the user in later
}

function changePlayers(playersSnap) {
   var ladderKey = playersSnap.parent().key();
   var numFetched = 0;
   var numPlayersToFetch = playersSnap.numChildren();
   var profiles = {};
   playersSnap.forEach(function(ss) {
      loadProfile(ss.key(), function(userSnap) {
         profiles[userSnap.key()] = userSnap.val();
         if( ++numFetched === numPlayersToFetch ) {
            updatePlayers(ladderKey, profiles);
         }
      });
   });
}

function updatePlayers(ladderKey, profiles) {
   // use whatever framework you have available to insert profiles
   // into the DOM
}

function loadProfile(key, callback) {
   usersRef.child(key).once('value', callback);
}

laddersRef.on('child_added', addLadder);
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the answer. What framework would you suggest?

Comment: We have official bindings for Angular, Ember, and React. I'd pick one of those. Angular and AngularFire are by far the most utilized, but I'd check out the getting started / hello world intros for each and utilize the one that seems most intuitive to you, as they are all amazing frameworks with great tools.